# Python iterator with sliced string

Tags: python, iterator, slice

I would like to have infinite iterator/generator with each turn return constant width sliced wrapped-around string. Dead simple code....

```
s = '123456789 '
it = my_iter(s, 9)
print(next(it))
print(next(it))
print(next(it))
print(next(it))
print(next(it))
```

will return:

```
123456789
23456789 
3456789 1
456789 12
```

I believe `cycle` form `intercools` can be helpful, but I can combine wrapping-around and slicing of `cycle`. Here is not wrapping version:

```
def my_iter(s, d):
    i = 0
    while True:
        yield s[i:d+i]
        i = i + 1
```

Comment: The simplest way would be to slice from s + s and use modulo to limit the index.

Answer (score 2):

The most natural rotation idiom uses `deque.rotate`:

```
from collections import deque

def my_iter(s, d):
    q = deque(s)
    while True:
        yield "".join(q)[:d]
        q.rotate(-1)

i = my_iter("123456789 ", 9)
for _ in range(15):
    print(next(i))

123456789
23456789 
3456789 1
456789 12
56789 123
6789 1234
789 12345
89 123456
9 1234567
 12345678
123456789
23456789 
3456789 1
456789 12
56789 123
```

Comment: Really like your solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restart the iterations once one cycle is over, try:

```
def my_iter(s, d):
    i = 0
    while True:
        if i > d:
            i = 0
        yield s[i:] + s[:max(0, i - 1)]
        i += 1
        
s = '123456789 '
it = my_iter(s, 9)
for _ in range(20):
    print(next(it))
```

Output:

```
123456789 
23456789 
3456789 1
456789 12
56789 123
6789 1234
789 12345
89 123456
9 1234567
 12345678
123456789 
23456789 
3456789 1
456789 12
56789 123
6789 1234
789 12345
89 123456
9 1234567
 12345678
```

---

Or if you want to give the same output as the previous runs, try:

```
def my_iter(s, d):
    i = 0
    while True:
        yield s[i:] + s[:max(0, i - 1)]
        i += 1

s = '123456789 '
it = my_iter(s, 9)
for _ in range(12):
    print(next(it))
```

Output:

```
123456789 
23456789 
3456789 1
456789 12
56789 123
6789 1234
789 12345
89 123456
9 1234567
 12345678
123456789
123456789
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct. This only seems to work if `d == len(s)-1`. Even in this case, for `i==0` the yielded element is longer than the others. You should probably yield `yield s[i:min(len(s), i+d)]+ s[0:max(0, i + d - len(s))]`